# Why is that an $n \times n$ matrix have $n$ eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is a silly question, but I can't find a good argument why an $n \times n$ matrix will have $n$ eigenvalues (not necessarily distinct).

In my linear algebra class the professor takes for granted that the number of eigenvalues is equal to the dimension of the matrix. For example, given eigs($A$) = $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, he will write a $5 \times 5$ dimensional matrix for $A$

How can we show this trivial fact?

Comment: It is not exactly trivial. In which field are the matrices? It reduces to zeros of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: When you find $det(A- \lambda I)$, you get an nth degree polynomial, which means you get n eigenvalues.

Comment: @paul so fundamental theorem of algebra

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An $n \times n$ matrix has a characteristic polynomial of order $n$. If the matrice's elements are from an **algebraically closed field**, then that means it must have at least one root. Then we can factor out a root and the remaining factor must also have at least one root et.c. Therefore there must be $n$ roots. The characteristic polynomial has eigenvalues as it's roots.

---

For example the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ are not algebraically closed, we can see this if we look at the polynomial equation $x^2+1 = 0$ which has no real roots. If we allow $x$ to be complex however it has the two famous roots $x = \pm i$.

Comment: I am new to all this, can you give me an example of a algebraically closed versus not closed fields? Thanks!

Comment: @MathNewb $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed. $\mathbb{R}$ is not. These are the two cases of interest the vast majority of the time.

Answer (score 2):

Affirmative if you are taking matrices over the complex numbers, although not necessarily distinct.

Over the real numbers the answer is sometimes a natural number $k$ between $0$ and $n$

Comment: Is there a trivial example showing that a real $ n \times n$ matrix does not have exactly $n$ eigenvalues?

Comment: @MathNewb A real matrix will have $n$ eigenvalues but some of them might be complex. A nice thing to look up is called the companion matrix for a polynomial; this is a way of going from a polynomial to a matrix whose eigenvalues are the roots of the polynomial.

Comment: @MathNewb Consider the rotation matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix},$$ which has no eigenvalues in the field $\mathbb{R}$ (but it has two distinct eigenvalues in the field $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: use the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right)$ for the case $2\times 2$

Comment: over $3\times3$ you could find that $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&-a&0\\a&0&0\\0&0&b\end{array}\right)$ with $a,b\in\Bbb R$ have only one real eigenvalue